# How to modify MadCap Flare's XML Sitemap Output?

Tags: xml, sitemap.xml

MadCap Flare generates a XML sitemap from the list of topics I have in HTML5 output. Does anyone know how I can modify the auto-generated sitemap to include *lastmod* and *description*?  Flare doesn't provide his functionality.

I tried modifying the Target XML file, but that did not work.

Comment: Still looking for this info if someone knows?